# env -i zsh | How is this magic possible?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, environment-variables

I'm currently working, for school, on a home-made shell, therefore I'm kind of curious nowadays about how shell vars are set. Yes, this can be really exciting !

Anyway, we obviously have to deal with the case when our shell will be launched with an empty environment, i.e. "env -i" command.
With env -i, the extern variable environ is absolutely empty, so we have to build ourselves a basic PATH, PWD and everything.

Our reference is csh, cause it's easy and simple. When you launch csh with env -i and then print it's variables, here is what you can see :

```
$ env -i csh
% set
addsuffix
argv    ()
csubstnonl
cwd /Users/noesierra-velasquez
dirstack    /Users/noesierra-velasquez
echo_style  bsd
edit
gid 20
group   staff
history 100
killring    30
owd
path    (/usr/bin /bin)
prompt  %
prompt2 %R?
prompt3 CORRECT>%R (y|n|e|a)?
shell   /bin/tcsh
shlvl   1
status  0
tcsh    6.17.00
tty ttys001
uid 501
user    noesierra-velasquez
version tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-apple-darwin) options         wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec
% env
HOSTTYPE=intel-mac
VENDOR=apple
OSTYPE=darwin
MACHTYPE=x86_64
SHLVL=1
PWD=/Users/noesierra-velasquez
LOGNAME=noesierra-velasquez
USER=noesierra-velasquez
GROUP=staff
HOST=MacBook-Pro-de-Noe-Sierra-Velasquez.local
REMOTEHOST=
```

Ok, so as you can see, there is no HOME set and it seems to me absolutely normal. If then you type `cd`, you'll get `cd: No home directory.`.
We live in a normal world.

But here is the magic. Type, inside your empty csh `env -i zsh`. zsh will load. Now print all env variables.
(Note : it perfectly works if you type directly `env -i zsh`, even from within zsh, I do it here this way only to be perfectly sure there is no tricky trick with zsh calling himself or whatever)

```
% env -i zsh
$ env
HOME=/Users/noesierra-velasquez
LOGNAME=noesierra-velasquez
SHLVL=1
PWD=/Users/noesierra-velasquez
OLDPWD=/Users/noesierra-velasquez
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Wow ! What happened !?
zsh seems to (and did) have a way to get back $HOME and $OLDPWD from what seems to me to be the pure nothingness.
(btw if anyone doesn't know, I'm pretty sure it uses paths.h to get back its path).

Obviously I know that "pure nothingness" is not a viable possibility, so I'm asking you guys : **Do you know how zsh is getting back HOME and OLDPWD ?**

Thank you for your patience and have a good day ! :)

Comment: Are you in `/Users/noesierra-velasquez` when you do this test? It’s probably just doing a `pwd` (or equivalent) and populating $PWD and $OLDPWD from the current directory. As for $HOME, it could be looking that up (not unlike what csh does when you refer to `~scott`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Actually, while writing this question, I thought it could be this ! So I tried to do the manipulation outside of the actual home directory... Result ? The same !
From wherever you do it, zsh always catches the right home directoy and oldpwd.

Comment: If you want to learn how the `zsh` shell actually does it, you could look at the source code http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/source.html .. might be a little much at first, but it's always great to have references when learning something exciting :)

Comment: I was actually reading it and yes that's exciting ! :D
Thing is we don't have much time and since we won't be implementing this particular feature, I'll have to stop my researches soon because of the time schedule.
Therefore I asked the community if anyone knew the answer but it seems like it's a mystery for most of us ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The documentation says the following about the `$HOME` variable:

   > `HOME <S>`
   >                 The default argument for the cd command.  This is not set automatically by the shell in sh, ksh or csh emulation, but  it 
   >   is  typically present in the environment anyway, and if it becomes set it has its usual special behaviour.

   I read it the other way round, when `zsh` is invoked by itself it gathers the informations about the homedir from the user management of the system. This (incomplete) snippet (from `Src/init.c`) serves as a proof:

   ```
   /* Get password entry and set info for `USERNAME' */
   if ((pswd = getpwuid(cached_uid))) {
       if (EMULATION(EMULATE_ZSH))
           home = metafy(pswd->pw_dir, -1, META_DUP);
   ...
   /*
   Try a cheap test to see if we can initialize `PWD' from `HOME'.
   In non-native emulations HOME must come from the environment;
   we're not allowed to set it locally.
   */
   if (EMULATION(EMULATE_ZSH))
     ptr = home;
   else
     ptr = zgetenv("HOME");
   ...
   ```

   So, with no emulation (i.e. ,,emulate zsh'') the homedir is determined by the `getpwuid` system call. Only otherwise, environment's `$HOME` is used.
2. I can't reproduce your ,,magic'' with `$PWD` and `$OLDPWD`. But perhaps you should consider to invoke zsh as `zsh -f`, so that no user- (zsh knows your homedir!) and system-wide settings get source'd. With that command I get the following environment on a debian box:

   ```
   $ pwd
   /tmp
   $ env -i zsh -f
   jessie% env
   HOME=/home/user
   LOGNAME=user
   SHLVL=1
   PWD=/tmp
   OLDPWD=/tmp
   _=/usr/bin/env
   jessie%
   ```

   So, no surprising values of `$PWD` and `$OLDPWD`. The source code setting these parameters follows directly to the above code:

   ```
   else if ((ptr = zgetenv("PWD")) && (strlen(ptr) < PATH_MAX) &&
       (ptr = metafy(ptr, -1, META_STATIC), ispwd(ptr)))
       pwd = ztrdup(ptr);
    else {
       pwd = NULL;
       pwd = metafy(zgetcwd(), -1, META_DUP);
    }
   ```

   oldpwd = ztrdup(pwd);  /* initialize `OLDPWD' =`PWD' */

   Hence, if `$HOME` is not set from the environment, a function `zgetcwd` is used. I didn't tracked this down, but I bet, it returns the *current working dir* `;)`. Finally `$OLDPWD` gets initialized with the same value.

*All examples and code snippets are taken from zsh 5.0.5-dev-0*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mpy for this precious information. It helped me a lot understanding how everything works.

I however founded a simple solution for getting back $HOME even when env is nul (as it was part of my assignment).
Following program works like a charm and use a NON-POSIX flag of the glob(3) function (so be careful checking if it exists in your `glob.h`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glob.h>

int                 main(void)
{
    glob_t          glob_info;
    unsigned int    i;
    int             ret;

    i = 0;
    if (!(ret = glob("~", GLOB_TILDE, NULL, &glob_info)))
    {
        while (i < glob_info.gl_pathc)
            printf("%s\n", glob_info.gl_pathv[i++]);
    }
    else
        printf("Glob error : %d\n", ret);
    return (0);
}
```

Please note that `glob(3)` is **not** made for this purpose originally.